# Is there a way to get all you tube videos into our site using embed code

Tags: video, youtube, web-scraping

Suppose i want to get all formula 1 Videos of You Tube into my website, is there a process to get all videos embed code so that i can directly place in my database? i hear of scraping web techniques can be used? can any one please help me in this way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the YouTube [APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html), particularly the [Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api). I imagine you should be able to put together a query that will get the Formula One videos that you're interested in.

> The Data API allows a program to
>   perform many of the operations
>   available on the YouTube website. It
>   is possible to search for videos,
>   retrieve standard feeds, and see
>   related content. A program can also
>   authenticate as a user to upload
>   videos, modify user playlists, and
>   more. The Data API is primarily for
>   developers who are used to programming
>   in server-side languages. It is useful
>   for sites or applications that wish to
>   have a deeper integration with
>   YouTube. This integration could be a
>   web application allowing users to
>   upload video to YouTube. It could also
>   be a device or desktop application
>   that brings the YouTube experience to
>   a new platform. The Data API gives you
>   programmatic access to the video and
>   user information stored on YouTube.